# TinyMCE content getting garbled upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, tinymce

I'm having an issue with TinyMCE. It seems that whenever the page is refreshed garbage characters are inserted into the content. Note that the content is being pasted from Word.

I am working on a CMS developed by someone else.. and when they have used TinyMCE in other pages in the system it doesn't seem to have this issue with the same content. I will post screenshots of the issue and also the code in how TinyMCE is invocated in the system. Basically it is automatically loaded for any textarea that has the class "wysiwyg."

The content as pasted in:

[image: the content as pasted in]

After refreshing:

[image: after refreshing]

Now there are very few garbage chars but I have sene where it refreshed and those A and gibberish looking characters are all over the place and sometimes appear to replace quite a bit of the content.

There is a lot of stuff concerning TinyMCE the plugins etc. but given that in other parts of the system it works fine and in what I'm doing it doesn't, I am thinking maybe it's what I'm doing-- but here's how the CMS loads TinyMCE:

```
var tinymceSettings = {
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url : '/include/core/plugins/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
    entity_encoding : "numeric",
    cleanup : true,
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "forecolor,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontsizeselect,|,cut,copy,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,anchor,link,unlink,image,media,|,code,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    content_css : "/admin/styles/wysiwyg.css",
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : true,
    file_browser_callback : "openKCFinder"
};

$(function() {
    $('.wysiwyg').tinymce(tinymceSettings);
});
```

Here's the text area I am using it in:

```
        <tr><td colspan="2">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea name="body" id="body" rows="20" cols="50" class="wysiwyg"><?php echo $order->getBody() ?></textarea>
        </td></tr>
```

Now this is saved in a database.. One thing that is odd is that TinyMCE doesn't sync it's data with the body textarea, so I have had to apply this code when clicking on the Save Changes button on the page:

```
$('#body').html(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
$.post("/price.php", $('#prnrequest').serialize(), function (data) {
    <?php if (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') : ?>
    $xprev.html(data);
    <?php endif; ?>
        if (notifyUser) {
            alert('Changes saved.');
            $('#saveText').hide();
            $('#saveButtons').show();
            enableSubmitButton();
        }
}, 'json');
```

And here is some code affecting the text area, don't know if this might be an issue or not:

```
$('input:not(:file), select, textarea').change(function(event) {
    disableSubmitButton();
});
```

And on Form submit this happens because the recipient needs all special entities to be escaped and not as themselves (ie. © has to be &copy; etc.):

```
aq_submitHandler = function () {
    $('form#prnrequest').submit(function () {
        $('#body').html(escapeHtmlEntities(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()));
        return true;
    });
}
```

And the .ready call:

```
$(function() {
    <?php if ($immediateDistribution) : ?>
    updateOrderInformation();
    <?php endif; ?>
    aq_submitHandler();
});
```

And finally the escapeHtmlEntities function:

```
escapeHtmlEntities = function (text) {
return text.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666<>\&]/g, function(c) {
    return '&' + 
    (escapeHtmlEntities.entityTable[c.charCodeAt(0)] || '#'+c.charCodeAt(0)) + ';';
});
};

// all HTML4 entities as defined here:     http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html
// added: amp, lt, gt, quot and apos
escapeHtmlEntities.entityTable = {
34 : 'quot', 
38 : 'amp', 
39 : 'apos', 
60 : 'lt', 
62 : 'gt', 
160 : 'nbsp', 
161 : 'iexcl', 
162 : 'cent', 
163 : 'pound', 
164 : 'curren', 
165 : 'yen', 
166 : 'brvbar', 
167 : 'sect', 
168 : 'uml', 
169 : 'copy', 
170 : 'ordf', 
171 : 'laquo', 
172 : 'not', 
173 : 'shy', 
174 : 'reg', 
175 : 'macr', 
176 : 'deg', 
177 : 'plusmn', 
178 : 'sup2', 
179 : 'sup3', 
180 : 'acute', 
181 : 'micro', 
182 : 'para', 
183 : 'middot', 
184 : 'cedil', 
185 : 'sup1', 
186 : 'ordm', 
187 : 'raquo', 
188 : 'frac14', 
189 : 'frac12', 
190 : 'frac34', 
191 : 'iquest', 
192 : 'Agrave', 
193 : 'Aacute', 
194 : 'Acirc', 
195 : 'Atilde', 
196 : 'Auml', 
197 : 'Aring', 
198 : 'AElig', 
199 : 'Ccedil', 
200 : 'Egrave', 
201 : 'Eacute', 
202 : 'Ecirc', 
203 : 'Euml', 
204 : 'Igrave', 
205 : 'Iacute', 
206 : 'Icirc', 
207 : 'Iuml', 
208 : 'ETH', 
209 : 'Ntilde', 
210 : 'Ograve', 
211 : 'Oacute', 
212 : 'Ocirc', 
213 : 'Otilde', 
214 : 'Ouml', 
215 : 'times', 
216 : 'Oslash', 
217 : 'Ugrave', 
218 : 'Uacute', 
219 : 'Ucirc', 
220 : 'Uuml', 
221 : 'Yacute', 
222 : 'THORN', 
223 : 'szlig', 
224 : 'agrave', 
225 : 'aacute', 
226 : 'acirc', 
227 : 'atilde', 
228 : 'auml', 
229 : 'aring', 
230 : 'aelig', 
231 : 'ccedil', 
232 : 'egrave', 
233 : 'eacute', 
234 : 'ecirc', 
235 : 'euml', 
236 : 'igrave', 
237 : 'iacute', 
238 : 'icirc', 
239 : 'iuml', 
240 : 'eth', 
241 : 'ntilde', 
242 : 'ograve', 
243 : 'oacute', 
244 : 'ocirc', 
245 : 'otilde', 
246 : 'ouml', 
247 : 'divide', 
248 : 'oslash', 
249 : 'ugrave', 
250 : 'uacute', 
251 : 'ucirc', 
252 : 'uuml', 
253 : 'yacute', 
254 : 'thorn', 
255 : 'yuml', 
402 : 'fnof', 
913 : 'Alpha', 
914 : 'Beta', 
915 : 'Gamma', 
916 : 'Delta', 
917 : 'Epsilon', 
918 : 'Zeta', 
919 : 'Eta', 
920 : 'Theta', 
921 : 'Iota', 
922 : 'Kappa', 
923 : 'Lambda', 
924 : 'Mu', 
925 : 'Nu', 
926 : 'Xi', 
927 : 'Omicron', 
928 : 'Pi', 
929 : 'Rho', 
931 : 'Sigma', 
932 : 'Tau', 
933 : 'Upsilon', 
934 : 'Phi', 
935 : 'Chi', 
936 : 'Psi', 
937 : 'Omega', 
945 : 'alpha', 
946 : 'beta', 
947 : 'gamma', 
948 : 'delta', 
949 : 'epsilon', 
950 : 'zeta', 
951 : 'eta', 
952 : 'theta', 
953 : 'iota', 
954 : 'kappa', 
955 : 'lambda', 
956 : 'mu', 
957 : 'nu', 
958 : 'xi', 
959 : 'omicron', 
960 : 'pi', 
961 : 'rho', 
962 : 'sigmaf', 
963 : 'sigma', 
964 : 'tau', 
965 : 'upsilon', 
966 : 'phi', 
967 : 'chi', 
968 : 'psi', 
969 : 'omega', 
977 : 'thetasym', 
978 : 'upsih', 
982 : 'piv', 
8226 : 'bull', 
8230 : 'hellip', 
8242 : 'prime', 
8243 : 'Prime', 
8254 : 'oline', 
8260 : 'frasl', 
8472 : 'weierp', 
8465 : 'image', 
8476 : 'real', 
8482 : 'trade', 
8501 : 'alefsym', 
8592 : 'larr', 
8593 : 'uarr', 
8594 : 'rarr', 
8595 : 'darr', 
8596 : 'harr', 
8629 : 'crarr', 
8656 : 'lArr', 
8657 : 'uArr', 
8658 : 'rArr', 
8659 : 'dArr', 
8660 : 'hArr', 
8704 : 'forall', 
8706 : 'part', 
8707 : 'exist', 
8709 : 'empty', 
8711 : 'nabla', 
8712 : 'isin', 
8713 : 'notin', 
8715 : 'ni', 
8719 : 'prod', 
8721 : 'sum', 
8722 : 'minus', 
8727 : 'lowast', 
8730 : 'radic', 
8733 : 'prop', 
8734 : 'infin', 
8736 : 'ang', 
8743 : 'and', 
8744 : 'or', 
8745 : 'cap', 
8746 : 'cup', 
8747 : 'int', 
8756 : 'there4', 
8764 : 'sim', 
8773 : 'cong', 
8776 : 'asymp', 
8800 : 'ne', 
8801 : 'equiv', 
8804 : 'le', 
8805 : 'ge', 
8834 : 'sub', 
8835 : 'sup', 
8836 : 'nsub', 
8838 : 'sube', 
8839 : 'supe', 
8853 : 'oplus', 
8855 : 'otimes', 
8869 : 'perp', 
8901 : 'sdot', 
8968 : 'lceil', 
8969 : 'rceil', 
8970 : 'lfloor', 
8971 : 'rfloor', 
9001 : 'lang', 
9002 : 'rang', 
9674 : 'loz', 
9824 : 'spades', 
9827 : 'clubs', 
9829 : 'hearts', 
9830 : 'diams', 
338 : 'OElig', 
339 : 'oelig', 
352 : 'Scaron', 
353 : 'scaron', 
376 : 'Yuml', 
710 : 'circ', 
732 : 'tilde', 
8194 : 'ensp', 
8195 : 'emsp', 
8201 : 'thinsp', 
8204 : 'zwnj', 
8205 : 'zwj', 
8206 : 'lrm', 
8207 : 'rlm', 
8211 : 'ndash', 
8212 : 'mdash', 
8216 : 'lsquo', 
8217 : 'rsquo', 
8218 : 'sbquo', 
8220 : 'ldquo', 
8221 : 'rdquo', 
8222 : 'bdquo', 
8224 : 'dagger', 
8225 : 'Dagger', 
8240 : 'permil', 
8249 : 'lsaquo', 
8250 : 'rsaquo', 
8364 : 'euro'
};
```

On that last one it being so long I didn't add extra spaces to every line to indent it the way it is in the code.

Been trying to solve this for a week now, and have no idea what the problem is. Also unable to find anything online about it.

This is a real bottleneck in this project and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example of it REALLY messed up: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4aqvv4q7u5r44du/Screenshot%202016-08-16%2021.06.16.png?dl=0

Comment: I am guessing it is an encoding problem. Check this and see if it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051710/utf-8-issues-with-tinymce